# 2005 PT Cruiser

Tags: lights, interior, pt-cruiser

2.4L Turbo

Interior lights coming on and off byself.

Door locks and unlocks byself.

Passenger door can only be locked manually.

Bought car 2 years ago used. Just noticed this happening.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!